# Python Command Line Checkboxes

Tags: python, python-2.7, checkbox, frontend, command-line-interface

I am new to Python 2.7 but I was wondering if it is possible to have checkboxes that are selectable by a user via the command line.

The only example I know of is yeoman (below) but its probably not written in Python.

[image]

Thank You

Comment: you need to look at curses or its variant for your OS ... its almost more difficult than making a real gui to be honest...

Comment: Tell us more about your need... is it for a command-line utility? console tool? sysadmin script? What platforms does it need to run on? Do you need Linux, Windows, Mac, mobile, web, what?

Answer (score 11):

Have a look at the [python-inquirer](https://github.com/magmax/python-inquirer) package.

To make a checkbox list you can do something like this:

```
import inquirer

questions = [inquirer.Checkbox(
    'interests',
    message="What are you interested in?",
    choices=['Computers', 'Books', 'Science', 'Nature', 'Fantasy', 'History'],
)]
answers = inquirer.prompt(questions)  # returns a dict
print(answers['interests'])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [beaupy](https://github.com/petereon/beaupy), which allows you to do something like this:

```
from beaupy import select_multiple
    
pizza_toppings = select_mutliple(['pineapple', 'olives', 'anchovies', 'mozzarella', 'parma ham']
                                 maximal_count=3,
                                 minimal_count=1)
```

Note: I am a maintainer of `beaupy` and this is nothing short of shameless self-promotion.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is generally not. For an easy gui look up [easy gui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net), or you might be looking for [raw input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input), where you can type your answer, for example

```
Want to do something? (Y/N)_ Y
```

Comment: It is 100 % possible using curses (py-curses + the curses library for your OS) ... not necessarilly easy, or sane, but certainly possible

Comment: You need to state briefly why IYO it is not easy.